# Insert only if statements are true

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement, insert

I want to build query which inserts row to table only if statement is true.
Well in my mind it should go like this (this is the easiest way - splitting it into multiple queries):

```
if((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE value1 = x)>0){
//response: already inserted
}else if((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE value2 = x AND value3 = true)>0){ //checking for very very other specific case 
//response: another error response - to tell user why action is wrong
}else{
INSERT INTO my_table value1, value2 ...
//response: ok
}
```

The easiest way is to split this into multiple queries and then use this algorithm, but I want to make it to be a single query, because I think the less rounds between connecting to db, querying, getting and fetching response etc. is much more efficient.

I was thinking about throwing custom mysql codes when statements are false, but I have no idea how the query itself should look like.

Comment: Are your app and the db on different continents?

Comment: Well, not yet :D
That concludes that multiple queries don't have much impact on performance (thanks), but what about high traffic case, or even what about good habits - Is my solution good?

Comment: No its not good. Your question is somewhat lacking too - explaining the code you want to write in terms of code which doesn't work is never a good idea - a proper narrative describing the logic is required here. I suspect that your first condition could be addressed simply with a unique constraint - but I can't make sense of your schema

Comment: I'd say - it's a bad habbit to worry about something, that might not exist :-). I'm pretty sure you will have other places in your code, which need more attention.

Comment: A) Use a `UNIQUE` index so it's impossible to duplicate things. B) Working code is always better than theoretically better but unimplemented code. C) Make an effort to split application concerns and database concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably not do that - But it's possible with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value1, value2, value3)
    SELECT 'x', 'y', true
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE value1 = 'x') 
                    THEN @error := 1
                WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE value2 = 'x' AND value3 = true)
                    THEN @error := 2
                ELSE @error := 0
            END AS error
    ) e
    WHERE e.error = 0;

SELECT @error;
```

However - you need at least two statements, because it's not possible to insert and select in one statement. But you can do that with one query, if your db library allows that.

The problem: Even if you find a more elegant (SQL only) solution, you will make the logic behind the code difficult to understand. And that will slow down the development and steal the time, which you will need to fix **real** performance bottlenecks.

Comment: This is what DBAs do when they don't know anything other than SQL. I'd agree, as you say it's not the best idea even if it could work.